# How to find the number of days worked without overlapping days

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to work out the total number of days a vehicle has been working in DAX, but have been unsuccessful so far. Below is my current table (Bold is not a column, it is showing what I hope to achieve)

```
JobNo     VehicleID     StartDate     EndDate     **DaysWorked**
1         1001          1/1/22        3/1/22      **3**
2         1001          3/1/22        5/1/22      **2**
3         1001          5/1/22        7/1/22      **2**
```

The total number of days worked here should be appearing as 7 (I've shown this in bold). If a Job starts on the same day that another one ends, it shouldn't count as another day of work.

Comment: just sum the datediffs

Comment: @mxix doing that for the above example would give me 6? Whereas the number of full days worked is actually 7

Answer (score 0):

If the only overlap is by start dates matching ending dates, have you tried making the formula to calculate the difference in days and substracting 1 when the start date is an end date of a row with the same vehicleID?
This won't work properly if later you filter the table

Comment: Thanks, it is essentially what i'm trying to do, but just unsure how to write a dax / calculated column formula for this. Not all end dates will overlap either

Comment: Ok, what I would do is a datediff to get the difference in days. Then I would add a - IF function that has a contains function on it's condition.

Comment: I'm not good enough to write DAX on the fly, but it would be something like this:

=
Var vVehicleID  = table.VehicleID
Var vStartDate = table.StartDate
Return
Datediff(startdate, enddate, day) - IF(contains(table, EndDate, vstartdate, vehicleid, vvehicleid),-1,0)